# Natural Organic slug/snail/pest repellants

Tags: pests, pest-control, snails, slugs

currently all of my plants seem to be getting devoured by slugs or snails or both. I'm currently growing the following.

- Mint
- Basil
- Sunflowers
- Tomatos
- Strawberrys
- Runner Beans

What can I do to reduce the slug/snail population?

I'm quite keen on the idea of encouraging wildlife that will eat the slugs/snails such as hedgehogs and birds, however I'm conscious that birds could then become a problem eating the fruit/veg.

I'm also wondering if there are any plants that deter slugs/snails, apparently mint is included in this, however they seem to enjoy eating it so not sure how effective this would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a slug problem this year too. I read that watering in the evening is a huge attractant for slugs because it leaves your garden moist all night, so if you're watering in the evening like I was, stop immediately and only water in early morning. Since I changed my watering schedule, the slugs haven't been too bad.

I've tried crushed eggshell at the base of plants, but the slugs don't seem to mind it. I've read about using copper strips to deter slugs (I guess it shocks them somehow), diatomaceous earth, beer traps, or salt spray as a last result. I have chickens and ducks that are kept away from the garden, but I hand-pick slugs in the evening and bring them to the hens to eat.

Slugs love moisture. Try to reduce slug habitat in your garden by reducing weeds and other damp slug hiding places.

Attracting birds is a great idea. They love shelter and perches. They can be a real nuisance with strawberries though (as can slugs!) so it might be good to cover your berries with some kind of row cover or bird netting. Your other plants should be unharmed by a greater presence of songbirds.

Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried using plants to discourage Slugs/Snails, not sure if this is something worth trying or not? knowing my luck they would eat them too.

Comment: I haven't tried this. I know there are such things as slug-resistant plants (things with fuzzy leaves seem to go untouched, like my oregano, tomatoes, and raspberries), but I doubt there is a plant that would keep slugs/snails repelled from your entire garden. If there is, I haven't found it! Supposed plants that repel are listed under #10 here: https://www.treehugger.com/ways-get-rid-slugs-naturally-4858817